# React/Redux with Material UI Boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am new in reactjs and got a new project to develop in react using redux. Client requirements are Reactjs+Material UI for frontend and Express+Mongo for backend API's. I have learned all these tech separately but I am now confused how do I put all these together to begin with the project.

Please help me, if anyone have developed the project in MERN stack recently please share the code, So I can follow the file structure and routes etc.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a google search? Not being sarcastic. There are a lot of tutorials and examples online for the MERN stack. Stack Overflow is better for more specific questions. I would also suggest an online course or book. Something like this https://www.udemy.com/mern-stack-front-to-back/.

Comment: Yes, Have searched a lot but not finding any specific tutorial for creating a full project.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, you just gave me a chance to show our demo project.

We are currently building a website using MERN and MUI, a coding assignment in our uni. You may use the git history to track how we built it. But i need to mention that it's not in a high quality because we are still learning this tech.

https://github.com/Latias94/Lovely-AIP

Any feedback is welcome~